# Proving that the language is in class P

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines, np-complete, decision-theory

I was asked to prove that the next language is in class P (polynomial):
 L={ $a$ | $a$ is a 3CNF and we can split the formula into two 3CNF formulas such that there exists an interpretation that satisfies them both}

I can't seem to understand why this problem can be solved in a polynomial time!

Comment: Looks weird to me. The two subformulas are satisfied by an interpretation if and only if the original formula is, so $L$ is the same as $3\text{-SAT}$.